# SQL Timeout for some users

Tags: sql-server

I have a web app that is currently timing out for some users, but when I run it myself it works quickly (< 5 seconds) even running it the same time the user is sitting and waiting for their query to come back.

I am running SQL Server 2008 Std (not R2). ASP.NET 4.0 with some gridviews and a local report viewer on the page. All the queries are contained in a stored procedure.

sp_whoisactive shows extremely high CPU and reads for their queries. 45k CPU, 30 million reads, 815 physical reads. No blocking sessions.

I even restarted the sql server service out of desperation, and the user is still having the issue, with them running it first, which makes me believe it isn't a parameter sniffing issue.

The only thing I can think of is that the query is selecting a bunch of data into a temp table and the tempDB is on the local hard drive instead of our NAS. It has been on my list to change.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Compare their *actual* execution plan to yours. Different SET options, different parameters, they may have a different default schema and reference objects without schema prefix, all of these may lead to a different (and less optimal) plan.

Comment: research "parameter sniffing" and see if that is a possible issue.  are you able to login as the (slow) user(s) and do the same thing?

Comment: Everyone logs into the server with the same user as far as SQL server is concerned. All the security is handled by the ASP.NET code (Integrated Login.. AD account.). The exact same procedure/options/parameters are being ran.

As mentioned above, I don't believe it is a parameter sniffing problem.